# multiple selectbox selection issue

Tags: drop-down-menu

I have created a multiple select-box.

when i select an item from select-box it removes that item so I cant select again or cant select that item multiple times.

for example I have the options (Apple, Strawberry, Mango) and I want to select Apple 2 times but I cant because when I selected it the first time it was removed from the select list.

is it possible to select one item several times from a select box?

```
<select name="name[]" multiple >
<option value='Apple'>Apple</option>
<option value='Strawberry'>Strawberry</option>
<option value='Mango'>Mango</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Why would you want to select on item several times though and for whatever reason it is I don't think that this is the correct control for the implementation.

Comment: i wan this because i created selectbox of multiple(fruit, price, address). i will put everything together and it will add multiple buyers together in the mysql

Comment: Why not create a form. Where each record is added with a unique ID so you can keep track of each unique order and when the form is submitted each time MySQL writes to your database

Comment: well it will make each order a unique id. Suppose, i select
(apple, apple, strawberry)
(usa, uk, austrailia)

it will save 3 unique records in the database using array

Comment: Then what you do is allow users to select the quantity of each item they desire in a separate field and also have a field in your database table to store it? how familiar are you with php/mysql?

Comment: already done as u said but i want this way also to enter the manual orders

Comment: I am sorry but I highly doubt the approach you are looking to take will work.